# How to remove header footer from particular page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I don't want header and footer from some particular page so how can I do this.

Comment: Go on layout file on particular module than paste the this code<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by below code in your layout xml file as :
**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\layout_file_name.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note :** If its admin page then you need to add the above code in the layout of that page as :

> Content -> Pages -> Select the Page -> Layout Update XML